# Arrange data into groups and use an aggregation function in a condition?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
TYPE            ID      PubID   Price
business        BU1032  1389    19,99
business        BU1111  1389    11,95
business        BU2075  0736    2,99
business        BU7832  1389    19,99
mod_cook        MC2222  0877    19,99
mod_cook        MC3021  0877    2,99
UNDECIDED       MC3026  0877    NULL
popular_comp    PC1035  1389    22,95
popular_comp    PC8888  1389    20,00
popular_comp    PC9999  1389    NULL
psychology      PS1372  0877    21,59
psychology      PS2091  0736    10,95
psychology      PS2106  0736    7,00
psychology      PS3333  0736    19,99
psychology      PS7777  0736    7,99
trad_cook       TC3218  0877    20,95
trad_cook       TC4203  0877    11,95
trad_cook       TC7777  0877    14,99
```

I want to group the rows by `PubID` but at the same time I need to evaluate a condition to retrieve the data. The condition is `AVG(price) >= 15`

I don't want show the average only I need it in a condition but I can't solve my problem.

1. I tried to use OVER clause but this need that the average be displayed in the results and I can't use over in the `where` clause

```
    select type,avg(price) over(partition by pub_id),pub_id from dbo.titles
    where avg(price) >= 15
```

2. I tried to use `GROUP BY` but I can't display the `type` field because doesn't appear in an aggregation function or in a `GROUP BY` clause

```
    select type from dbo.titles
    group by pub_id
    having avg(price) >= 15
```

How can I show the type and group by `pub_id`?

**UPDATE:**

**Expected result:**

Because avg(price) are greater or equal 15 these are displayed:

I need to group the rows by pubID

```
TYPE
---------------
Businness        
popular_comp
psychology_comp
trad_cook
```

Comment: Can you show what is the expected result ?

Comment: You can add `type` also into the `group by` clause since one `pub_id` always belongs to one `type` as per the given data

Comment: Sorry, but your statement `I want to group the rows by PubID` & `How can I show the type and group by pub_id` is not making any sense to me. Can you explain further. Also can you explain why `mod_cook` is not in the result ?

Answer (score 0):

If i follow correctly, you want to discover which PubId has an Average Price >= 15?

If so, then it needs to be a 2-step query. Firstly to get the averages and filter out the unwanted PubId and then select and group the Types:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Titles (
    [Type] varchar(20),
    [ID] char(6),
    [PubId] char(4),
    [Price] decimal(4,2)
)

INSERT dbo.Titles
VALUES 
('business',        'BU1032',  '1389',    19.99),
('business',        'BU1111',  '1389',    11.95),
('business',        'BU2075',  '0736',    2.99 ),
('business',        'BU7832',  '1389',    19.99),
('mod_cook',        'MC2222',  '0877',    19.99),
('mod_cook',        'MC3021',  '0877',    2.99 ),
('UNDECIDED',       'MC3026',  '0877',    NULL ),
('popular_comp',    'PC1035',  '1389',    22.95),
('popular_comp',    'PC8888',  '1389',    20.00),
('popular_comp',    'PC9999',  '1389',    NULL ),
('psychology',      'PS1372',  '0877',    21.59),
('psychology',      'PS2091',  '0736',    10.95),
('psychology',      'PS2106',  '0736',    7.00 ),
('psychology',      'PS3333',  '0736',    19.99),
('psychology',      'PS7777',  '0736',    7.99 ),
('trad_cook',       'TC3218',  '0877',    20.95),
('trad_cook',       'TC4203',  '0877',    11.95),
('trad_cook',       'TC7777',  '0877',    14.99);

WITH AvgPrices
AS (
    SELECT [PubId],
       AVG([Price]) as AvgPrice
    FROM dbo.Titles
    GROUP BY [PubId] 
)
SELECT p.[PubId],
       p.[Type]
FROM dbo.Titles p
JOIN AvgPrices av ON av.PubId = p.PubId AND av.AvgPrice >= 15.0
GROUP BY p.[PubId], p.[Type];
```

Result is:

```
PubId   Type
0877    mod_cook
0877    psychology
0877    trad_cook
0877    UNDECIDED
1389    business
1389    popular_comp
```